# How to recognize one item belong to which group when load a plist file?

Tags: iphone

I use codes below to load plist file

```
    NSDictionary* tSetDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
NSArray* prefs = [tSetDict objectForKey:@"PreferenceSpecifiers"];

// Iterate through dictionaries to find required value
for (NSDictionary* setDict in prefs){

            //.........
    }
}
```

I hope to know setDict belongs to which group (section).

Is it possible?

Welcome any comment

Thanks

interdev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I understand your question correctly but I will try anyways....

Use the simple/slow iteration:

```
for (int i=0;i < [prefs count];++i)
{
  NSDictionary *setDict = [prefs objectAtIndex:i];
  NSLog(@"got the dict from section %d", i);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I mean when iPhone app 'Setting' loads setting.bundle plist file. It will load the groups(PSGroupSpecifier) one by one(in each group there are elements PSToggleSwitchSpecifier, PSSliderSpecifier,  PSTitleValueSpecifier, PSTextFieldSpecifier)

Comment: and app 'Settings' will display the groups in different sections of a UITableView.

Comment: Now, if I have got the element(PSToggleSwitchSpecifier, PSSliderSpecifier, PSTitleValueSpecifier, PSTextFieldSpecifier) how can I know it belongs to which group.

Comment: for example:PSTextFieldSpecifier

Comment: it has keys:Title, Key, DefaultValue, IsSecure, KeyboardType, AutocapitalizationType,AutocorrectionType. But there is no key to indicate the "Text Field Element"(Type:PSTextFieldSpecifier) belong to which group.

Comment: I found it look likes app "Settings" load a “Group Element”(type:PSGroupSpecifier) at first, then display all elements/items follow it in a same group until load the next “Group Element”(type:PSGroupSpecifier). The next “Group Element”(type:PSGroupSpecifier) and the elements follow it will display in the next group/section.

Comment: Sorry I got you wrong. For the future: use the comment section for shortly describing issues with the solution posted. If you need to rephrase or enhance your question, use the Edit-function of your original question.